# How to delete a certificate from Mac Keychain through code?

Tags: macos, security, certificate, keychain

I've looked into [Apple's Certificate reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Security/Reference/certifkeytrustservices/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30000157), and I don't see anything about removing certificates from the Keychain.

Is it allowed?

If so, how? If not, why not?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Certificates are a subtype of keychain items, so you can use `SecKeychainItemDelete` to remove them. To prevent compiler warnings, you'll need to explicitly cast the `SecCertificateRef` to a `SecKeychainItemRef` — plain C doesn't have language support for subclasses.

```
SecCertificateRef certificate = ...;
OSStatus status = SecKeychainItemDelete((SecKeychainItemRef)certificate);
if (status) {
    // Handle error
}
```

If you target Mac OS 10.6 or later, you can also use the newer `SecItemDelete` API. It doesn't provide any advantages in the simplest case, but you can change the query argument to delete multiple certificates at once, or delete certificates without having direct references to them.

```
SecCertificateRef certificate = ...;
NSDictionary *query = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                       kSecClassCertificate, kSecClass,
                       [NSArray arrayWithObject:(id)certificate], kSecMatchItemList,
                       kSecMatchLimitOne, kSecMatchLimit,
                       nil];    
OSStatus status = SecItemDelete((CFDictionaryRef)query);
if (status) {
    // Handle error
}
```